# Google Firebase Android app receiving wrong db information from DataSnapshot

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an android app that require Google Firebase, and in the app I have to iterate through datasnapshots a couple of times. In one specific instance, the datasnapshop is passing data from a different directory in the database than what it is specified to. I make a reference to the database, then add an event listener that calls an onDataChange method which passes a datasnapshot through. Here:

```
    nRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
    nRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                showDataLobReq(dataSnapshot);
                showData(dataSnapshot);
            } else {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

And here are the methods that this calls:

```
public void showDataLobReq(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child("Lobby_Requests").getChildren()){
        System.out.println("here"+ds.getValue());
        game = ds.child(userID).child("game").getValue(String.class);
        console = ds.child(userID).child("console").getValue(String.class);
        mic = ds.child(userID).child("mic").getValue(String.class);
        players = ds.child(userID).child("players").getValue(String.class);
    }


}

public void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    ArrayList<LobbyInformation> Lobbies = new ArrayList<>();

    Iterator<DataSnapshot> items = dataSnapshot.child("Lobbies").getChildren().iterator();
    Lobbies.clear();
    while(items.hasNext()){
        LobbyInformation lobby = new LobbyInformation();
        DataSnapshot item = items.next();
        lobby.setGameName(item.child("game").getValue(String.class));
        lobby.setConsole(item.child("console").getValue(String.class));
        lobby.setMic(item.child("mic").getValue(String.class));
        lobby.setNote(item.child("note").getValue(String.class));
        lobby.setPlayerCountTotal(item.child("players").getValue(String.class));
        lobby.setHost(userID);

        if(console.equals(item.child("console").getValue(String.class)) &&
                players.equals(item.child("players").getValue(String.class)) &&
                mic.equals(item.child("mic").getValue(String.class)) &&
                game.equals(item.child("game").getValue(String.class))){

            Lobbies.add(lobby);
        }

    }
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapterLobby(this, Lobbies);
    lobbyListView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

In the first method it calls "showDataLobReq" you can see I use system.out.println to see the contents of the datasnapshot, and I discovered it is showing the contents for the child of the datasnapshot i iterate through in the second method "showData". I have no idea why it is like this considering I clearly define the correct child in the enhanced for loop at the beginning of the method "showDataLobReq".